# Angular 2 HTTP GET to Node backend for list of file names in directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to use an Angular 2 HTTP GET request to simply connect with a Node/Express backend that responds with a list of the file names in a certain folder using the fs.readdir method.

I set up the Angular 2 request as a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import './rxjs-operators';

@Injectable()
export class PhotoService {

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  private photosUrl = '/api/photos';  // URL to web API

  getPhotos() : Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.photosUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

and then called this service from a component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.photoService.getPhotos()
                     .subscribe(
                        photos => this.fileList = photos,
                        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

This is the Node backend (with Express set up as per conventions):

```
//Photo Service
app.get('/api/photos', function(req, res) {
        fs.readdir('./uploads', function(error, files) {
          if (error) {
            throw error;
          }
          else {
            res.end(files);
          }
        });
});
```

As seen, the HTTP request calls a GET method to http://localhost:3000/api/photos and the Node backend is supposed to receive that request and send back an array of strings that have the names of files in the 'uploads' folder.

However it does not seem to be working. I think I'm getting confused with the format in which the Node API sends the response and how that works with the Observable type that Angular uses in the service.

Answer (score 2):

Your Angular 2 code looks good to me. But in your Node backend you should not send data with `res.end()` (see the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.end)). Correct would be `res.send(files);` or in your case `res.json(files);` which will also set the right `Content-Type` header.